How to save Get-FileHash output to a file using a for loop?
I am using a for loop to find the hash values of files (I am doing this to 10,000 files):
for ($var = 0; $var -le 9999; $var++) {
    Get-FileHash -Path C:\Users\Name\Documents\Filename$var.txt
}

However, I want to save the outputs of the file to a separate file to be able to search for a specific hash value.  This is the command I have for that so far:
for ($var = 0; $var -le 9999; $var++) {
    Get-FileHash -Path C:\Users\Name\Documents\Filename$var.txt | 
        Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Name\Documents\HashFiles.txt
}

This code is rewriting the file each time, so I was wondering how I would be able to keep all of the hash values that I search?  Also, if anyone has any tips for how to write the file's name before the hash, that would also be helpful.  TYIA!

The output from Get-FileHash already contains the file's absolute path, you will have an easier time when looking at the hashes if you export this output to a CSV instead:
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Name\Documents -Filter Filename*.txt |
    Select-Object -First 9999 |
    Get-FileHash |
    Export-Csv C:\Users\Name\Documents\HashFiles.csv -NoTypeInformation

If you want to also add the file's name (in addition to their absolute path) you can add an additional piping to Select-Object with a calculated property:
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Name\Documents -Filter Filename*.txt -PipelineVariable file |
    Select-Object -First 9999 |
    Get-FileHash |
    Select-Object @{ N='FileName'; E={ $file.Name }}, * |
    Export-Csv C:\Users\Name\Documents\HashFiles.csv -NoTypeInformation


Would I place this inside my for loop instead?  I did that and I'm only seeing my last file.  I used  --  for ($var = 0; $var -le 9999; $var ++) { Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Name\Documents -Filter file$var.txt | Select-Object -First 9999 | Get-FileHash | Export-Csv C:\Users\Name\Documents\HashFiles.csv -NoTypeInformation }  --  I used the $var in the file name because its file0 to file9999 as the names, but I'm not sure if I needed to do that for this or not?  If I can move them into the csv file with their hash, I'll be able to find what I need.  Very grateful for your help!
